# Dependency of Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

I would love for some help in a pretty basic thing.
Say I have two Bernoulli random variables: $X$ and $Y$ with the same parameter $p$.
First, is $X = Y$ since their parameter is equal?
Second, can I say something about the variables' dependency? Dependent or independent?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without any other information, one may or may not have $X=Y$, and $X$ and $Y$ may or may not be independent.

Comment: @tristan I asking this because I'm asked to find E(XY) (it's only a part of the question...) and that is all the information I got about X and Y. Do you have any idea for a possible solution?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independant, then $\mathbb{E}(XY)=p^2$. If $X=Y$, then $\mathbb{E}(XY)=p$. There are infinitely many other possible answers, depending on the law of the couple $(X,Y)$. Without other information, one cannot answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily and no.

Consider flipping two coins. Let $X$ model the first coin and $Y$ the second. In this case, clearly $X \neq Y$ (the first coin can come up heads and the second tails), and $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

On the other hand, we could have both $X$ and $Y$ model the same coin flip. In this case, $X = Y$, and $X$ and $Y$ are clearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Well!.... $X=Y$ doesn't mean in probability space at all! But it can be fixed. In fact the true statement is:

$X=Y \quad inp$ $\Leftarrow\Rightarrow Pr(X=Y)=1$

This is called to be probabilistic equality.

As another example take $X_n\sim Bern({1\over n})$ for $n \in \Bbb N$ and $X\sim Bern(0)$. Then $Lim_{n\to \infty}{Pr(X_n=X)}=1$ since their distributions are tending to that of X. There are so many examples like this one. Also I recommend you to do a search a about "A.E.P." which stands for "Asymptotic Equipartition Probability" and the "Weak Law of Large Numbers"